# How is NFC intent filter selection affected by filter details?

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter

Suppose that there are two apps which registered the following `intent-filter`s in their AndroidMenifest.xml.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"
        android:host="developer.android.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/index.html" />
</intent-filter>
```

VS

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In this case, between the two apps, which NFC filter is in effect?

My ultimate goal is to develop an app which dispatches the tag preferentially only if the url in tag starts from "http://developer.android.com/index.html", otherwise the other app can dispatch the other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more specific intent filter will take precedence. Thus, the activity with the first intent filter (the one that includes a data tag) will win.

Comment: In this specific case, an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent filter without any specific filter for the NDEF data, may on some phones never be triggered (e.g. Galaxy S3).

Comment: Could you explain why? Are you refering to http/https URIs only or to any NDEF records? Thinking about it, for http/https you might actually be right (not only for S3 but most likely for all phones) because web browsers will already have a more specific an intent filter (one with <data android:scheme="http" /> and one with <data android:scheme="https" />) registered that takes precedence over the generic one. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I observed this behaviour in some phones (I am positive about the S3 when it first came out). I consider it a bug, because it differs from the behaviour on Nexus devices.